# 10pt font only 9% smaller than 12pt font?

Tags: fontsize

When changing a file with the class

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extbook}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{extbook}
```

I noticed that `\normalsize` parts are only about 9% smaller than before, while I expected 20%. The length of sentences also decreases only by 9%. I use the standard CM fonts. This appears to contradict the actual font sizes listed at
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Sizing_text
Can anyone please enlighten me as what is going on?

Comment: Hi! Do you mean smaller in height or in width?

Comment: I get 6.83331pt for the height of an ‘A’ at 10pt, and 8.2pt at 12pt size. The ratio is 1.2. The ratio of the widths is 1.17; not 1.2, because Computer Modern fonts are not geometrically scaled.

Comment: You should expect 17% smaller, because 10/12 ≈ 0.83; can you tell how you get 9%?

Comment: You should expect 15% smaller based on the sizes given on the page you linked to since the ratio of the 10pt to 12pt size given there for `\normalsize` is .85.